# Не работает fetch

Tags: php, smarty, хостинг

Всем привет.Сразу к делу.
Не работает эта строчка, из-за которой не работает весь сайт. Проблема появилась в ходе переезда на новый хост.

```
$box_categories = $box->fetch(CURRENT_TEMPLATE.'/boxes/box_categories.html');
```

Файл `box_categories.html`:

```
{config_load file="$language/lang_$language.conf" section="boxes"}
<!-- Бокс разделы -->
<div id="boxCategories">
<h5><span>{#heading_categories#}</span></h5>
<div id="categoriesBoxMenu">{$BOX_CONTENT}</div>
</div>
<!-- /Бокс разделы -->
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо

Comment: сдеайте в шаблоне дебаг объекта $box, вполне может быть, что туда попадает не то что вы ожидаете

Comment: А что в CURRENT_TEMPLATE храните не покажете?

Comment: Та же проблема. Есть кстати там ещё функция template_exists(), её можно проверить правильность пути, у меня возвращает true, а вот на fetch php падает